How to alter column type without exceeding disk space limitations
I have a table with ~20million rows which currently occupies about 30gb. There is an additional 30gb free on this database.
I have one column that was imported as text but needs to be converted to jsonb. It's pretty simple and is an array with up to 100 values inside.
Below is an example of converting just one of these strings
select to_jsonb('[45,45,45,55]'::json);

And then on the entire column
ALTER TABLE pointstable ALTER COLUMN aimjoined TYPE jsonb USING to_jsonb(aimjoined::json);

Running this progresses for about 30minutes and then fails. I can see disk space get close to 100% full before it fails.
Is there another way to change this column to jsonb that won't overrun my disk space? Perhaps in batches or another method altogether?

@Hard_Coder - so limit the number of rows on each alter? Do them in batches? Can you alter column type for just a few rows?

Might be easiest to handle during import if that's possible. Perhaps CREATE TABLE with aimjoined specified as jsonb.


Can you alter column type for just a few rows?

No.

@IanGow - I agree - There has to be a way to efficiently update a column type without doubling the table size though right?

One way I can see doing this create column aimjoined_temp jsonb on the table. Then update that column in transaction batches(to allow  VACUUM to recycle tuples) using aimjoined::jsonb. Verify that aimjoined_temp has all the data, then drop the aimjoined column and rename aimjoined_temp to aimjoined. Do a test run of this on smaller test table to verify process before attempting the whole table run.

@Hard_Coder LIMIT is not supported in an ALTER TABLE statement.

Drop any indexes on the table before altering it.  When altering it, new indexes need to be built while the old indexes are still around.  Dropping indexes first frees up their space twice, the space of the old index is available to be reused, the new index doesn't need to built as part of the ALTER command.  (Once the ALTER command is committed, then the old table goes away, and it space is available to be used in building the new indexes).

This helped free up some space.. I ended up creating an empty column of type jsonb then filling it with values from my other column. Seemed to be slightly less disk intensive
